# Compare string with slashes

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison

I have two strings which look like this:

> string a = "C:\Temp\1.png"
>
> string b = "C:\Temp\1.png"

Those, of course, have the same meaning.
I'm looking for a way to know that they're equal.

Meaning, something like:

```
bool areEqual = false;    
if (a.CompareTo(b) == 0)
      areEqual = true;
```

And for the example above, `areEqual` will be `true`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Did you even try it before asking it here ?

Comment: I tried and it fails, for some reason...

Comment: @Idanis What _reason_?

Comment: @Steve it seems to me that he is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code

```
string a = @"C:\xxx\1.png";
string b = @"C:\xxx\1.png";

bool blnEqule = a == b;
```

Answer (score 2):

`a == b` should do what you want. Contents (slashes or not) should not have any effect on comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Try `a.Equals(b) == true` or plain `a == b` it doesn't matter.

If you want to tailor your code for using paths another approach would be to use `FileInfo` objects to parse that path for you and check if they point to the same file.

Comment: Just a tip; `.Equals()` method has some overloads which provides some _culture-aware comparison_ on strings.

Answer (score 0):

Actually given CONTEXT what the OP WANTED was the following

```
var a = "C:\\Temp\\1.png";
var b = "C:\\tEmP\\1.PNG";      
var isEquals = a.Equals(b, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
Console.WriteLine(isEquals);
```

Assuming that this is going to be run on a windows system, the NTFS system is CASE INSENSITIVE.

PS. Download Linqpad to do your C# prototyping, will save you many many hours.